# Hibernate with two foreign keys from same table- annotation

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I'm trying to design a hospitality app. I have two tables as `User` and `Request`. Users could be `Host` or `Visitor` and can send host request to each other. but there is no need to define Users as visitor or host, it doesn't matter for the system so I don't have seperate tables for them. This difference is just important in Request table and it's needed to keep `visitor_id` and `host_id` as foreign keys (mapped with `user_id` primary key column from User table because both host and visitor are also User).

My question is how can I define this relation in hibernate with `Annotation`? I mean, there should be two foreign keys in Request table and they're mapped to *user_id* primary key column from User table. Every user can be host or visitor many times and makes none or many requests.

```
@Entity
public class Request {
@Id
private Long req_id;

 ....

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A request is for a host, and from a visitor, So you simply have 2 ManyToOne associations from Request to User:

```
@Entity
public class Request {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "req_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "visitor_id")
    private User visitor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "host_id")
    private User host;

    // ...
}
```

If you want to make these associations bidirectional, then you simply need corresponding collections in the user:

```
@Entity
private class User {

    /**
     * requests made to this user, in order for this user to be a host
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "host")
    private Set<Request> hostRequests = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * requests made by this user, in order for this user to be a visitor
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "visitor")
    private Set<Request> visitorRequests = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have similar kind table with hibernate. It is working fine, I am facing problem with Jackson forward and backward references. Like Only one column be made references in Jackson, if I make other 500 erros comes

Comment: how to query them using HQL with inner join? Since "ON" clause is not present in hql inner join ?

Comment: @user1735921 you don't need ON in this case (although it does exist in HQL). Read the documentatin. A whole section is dedicated to joins in HQL.