# Hibernate : Two Foreign Keys from the same Table

Tags: java, hibernate

I've one table named *Stat* and Other named *Request*, in the request table i've to attributs :  *Old_Stat* and *New_Stat*, both are referencing into the same table Stat.
But when using Hibernate to make relation between the two tables, i dont know how to say to Hibernate that those two attributes are foreign keys on the same table Stat. 
I wish someone can help me to **fix** this problem.

This is my code proposition :

```
@Entity
public class Request implements Serializable{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Integer Request_id;
     ..... 

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stat_id")
private Stat stat_new;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stat_id")
private Stat stat_old;
}
    /** in The Stat Class **/

@Entity
public class Stat implements Serializable{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Integer stat_id;
   ..... 

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "stat_old",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Request> requests;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "stat_new",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Request> requestss;
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate with two foreign keys from same table- annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954787/hibernate-with-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table-annotation)

Comment: No, in his case, they are one table as parent and two tables as children, in my case, i have just one table.

Comment: your join columns both have the same name

Comment: As @Jungkook mentioned, you define 2 columns with same name "stat_id".

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, they are referencing to the same table, so the same Id.
I need other proposition please.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your trying to join `stat_id` column in your `Request` entity and it does not exists. Even if it did, you can't join column two times without one having `updateable=false` and `insertable=false`.

The most probably, this will resolve your problem.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stat_new", referencedColumnName= "stat_id")
private Stat stat_new;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stat_old", referencedColumnName= "stat_id")
private Stat stat_old;
```