# How to use one column in two foreign keys?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible to have one column in two foreign keys, because I get error when i use it? My table with two foreign keys looks like this:

```
package com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model;

import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.id.OperacijaId;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(value = OperacijaId.class)
@Table(name = "OPERACIJA")
public class Operacija implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "O_ID")
    private Integer operacijaId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="PROIZVOD_TC_ID", referencedColumnName="PROIZVOD_TC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="PROIZVOD_CP_ID", referencedColumnName="PROIZVOD_CP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="TP_ID", referencedColumnName="TP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="TEP_ID", referencedColumnName="TEP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private TehnoloskiPostupak tehnoloskiPostupak;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="PROIZVOD_TC_ID", referencedColumnName="TC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="PROIZVOD_CP_ID", referencedColumnName="CP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="SASTAVNICA_DEO_TC_ID", referencedColumnName="DEO_TC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="SASTAVNICA_DEO_CP_ID", referencedColumnName="DEO_CP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Sastavnica sastavnica;

    @Column(name = "O_NAZIV")
    private String naziv;

    @Column(name = "O_OPIS")
    private String opis;

    @Column(name = "O_VREME_TRAJANJA")
    private Integer vremeTrajanja;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operacija")
    List<UtrosakProizvodnje> utrosciProizvodnje;
}
```

with OpercaijaId class:

```
package com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.id;

import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.Sastavnica;
import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.TehnoloskiPostupak;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class OperacijaId implements Serializable {

    private Sastavnica sastavnica;

    private TehnoloskiPostupak tehnoloskiPostupak;

    private Integer operacijaId;
}
```

and that works fine. But problem is when I refer object Operacija in class UtrosakProizvodnje:

```
package com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model;

import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.id.CinilacPoslovanjaId;
import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.id.UtrosakProizvodnjeId;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(value = UtrosakProizvodnjeId.class)
@Table(name = "UTROSAK_PROIZVODNJE")
public class UtrosakProizvodnje implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="CINILAC_PROIZVODNJE_TC_ID", referencedColumnName="TC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="CINILAC_PROIZVODNJE_CP_ID", referencedColumnName="CP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private CinilacPoslovanja cinilacPoslovanja;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="PROIZVOD_TC_ID", referencedColumnName="PROIZVOD_TC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="PROIZVOD_CP_ID", referencedColumnName="PROIZVOD_CP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="SASTAVNICA_DEO_TC_ID", referencedColumnName="SASTAVNICA_DEO_TC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="SASTAVNICA_DEO_CP_ID", referencedColumnName="SASTAVNICA_DEO_CP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="TP_ID", referencedColumnName="TP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="TEP_ID", referencedColumnName="TEP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="O_ID", referencedColumnName="O_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Operacija operacija;

    @Column(name = "UP_KOLICINA")
    private double kolicina;
}
```

which has an ID class too:

```
package com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.id;

import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.CinilacPoslovanja;
import com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.Operacija;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UtrosakProizvodnjeId implements Serializable {

    private Operacija operacija;

    private CinilacPoslovanja cinilacPoslovanja;

}
```

and the problem is when I start springboot app, I get error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.proizvodnja_mleka_backend.model.UtrosakProizvodnje._identifierMapper type: component[cinilacPoslovanja,operacija]
```

I think the problem is in columns 'PROIZVOD_TC_ID' and 'PROIZVOD_CP_ID'(because when i try to map this without Operacija or CinilacPoslovanja ie. to have just one foreign key with these columns, it works), but I don't know how to solve this example.Is it possible to solve this problem or I need to use some other solutions(e.g. only one id field for UtrosakProizvodnje)?

Comment: you may want to check this solution, i think this can be your solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954787/hibernate-with-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table-annotation

Comment: I check this and I don't understand how this can help, or what I can do with this, but thanks again.

Comment: You want to use one column in two different foreign keys right ? You can add your inner entity twice with different foreign keys. By the way , can you try with removing multiple @Id annotation from your class, this is not JPA compliant it may occur your exception.

Comment: Actually, I can't add my inner entity twice because my entity 'Operacija' has two different inner entities('Sastavnica' & 'TehnoloskiPostupak') which are both id dependent of entity 'CinilacPoslovanja' and both entities(in entity 'Operacija') need to have same 'CinilacPoslovanja'. That is the reason why I can have only two columns('Proizvod_TC_ID' and 'Proizvod_CP_ID') instead of four(two for part of primary key of 'Sastavnica' and two for 'TehnoloskiPostupak') and I can't remove multiple @Id annotation because I have pks of two entities and one field in my pk for entity 'Operacija'.